# Disabled navigation buttons and tab bar dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have an app with navigation bar, tab bar and I have a button that, when I push it, it do some things. Well, I'd like to disable the navigation buttons(back button for example) and the tab bar buttons in order to avoid that the user push other buttons while the button's action is running.
Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: that works perfectly for the navigation bar. Now it's time to disable the tab bar :P